# ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000) Issue with logging into MySQL DB using Python script and Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, python, mysql

I have created a Python script that does some calculations and then points to a DB to fill out some tables. The DB is hosted on a Ubuntu Azure VM, where I set up a MySQL database. I have been able to write tables to the DB using a local DB (in Windows) and the following code, but when I try loging into the DB using Linux and the `mysql.connector` package, I get a:
`ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

'admin' is the name of the Azure VM that is hosting the server. I have tried using the DB root and its p/w, as well as another DB user name & p/w combination I have created and I get the same error. Any help is kindly appreciated.

```
def save_df_to_mysql_db(df, database_name, table_name, username='', password='', host='', port=''):
    # Initialize the configparser
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    # Read the config.ini file
    config.read('config_linux.ini')

    # Get the database configuration values
    db_config = {
        'port': config.get('DB', 'port'),
        'host': config.get('DB', 'host'),
        'username': config.get('DB', 'username'),
        'password': config.get('DB', 'password')
    }
    # Connect to MySQL database
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=username, password=password, host=host, port=port, auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    # Create database if it doesn't exist
    cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {database_name}")
    conn.database = database_name
    
    # Create SQLAlchemy engine
    engine = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{db_config['user']}:{db_config['password']}@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['database']}")
    
    # Save DataFrame to MySQL database
    df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    
    # Close connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print(f"Dataframe {df} saved to {table_name} of {database_name}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

## To resolve this issue, you should ensure that:

1. The user 'admin' exists in your MySQL database.
2. The password for the user 'admin' is correct.
3. The user 'admin' has the necessary privileges to access the database specified in your connection string.

- If you're using the create_engine function from SQLAlchemy, ensure that you're providing the correct password in the connection string. Here's an example of how you might modify your connection string to include the password:
  `engine = create_engine(f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{db_config['user']}:{db_config['password']}@{db_config['host']}:{db_config['port']}/{db_config['database']}")`